# Merging lyx files involving different (perhaps intersecting) macros

Tags: macros, lyx, collaboration

I want to merge two files written in LyX by my colleague and me. 
The problem is both of us use self-written macros for writing things shortly.

We want to merge our files, and use a chapter my colleague wrote in his file, inside the main file I wrote, while using different macros.

The macros aren't complex (as we're both self-taught lyx users, not power users), but every one of us has a couple tens of them, and each macro is used tens-hundreds of times.

**What is a relatively simple way to merge part of my colleague's file into mine?**

One thing I was thinking is a feature that somehow "dissolves" the macros, converting them to a "normal" chars inside a math box, as if they never were macros.

I'd appreciate any suggestion

Thanks :)

Comment: If lyx can merge files (I have no idea if it can do it) then it should be possible to simply copy the macro definitions in your preamble.